# how to get encryption status(yes/no) of an iSCSI sotrage using an API in SoftLayer

Tags: encryption, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

[image: Image showing the details of a particular iSCSI storage]

def get_iscsi(self, volume_id, **kwargs)

I have used this method to fetch the details of a particular storage component, but I am unable to pull the encryption status with the help of API services.

Which API can be used to extract encryption status of iSCSI storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Retrieve child accounts from account

```
"""
This script retrieves account's brand and owned accounts (child accounts) 

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBrand
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand/getOwnedAccounts

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    brand = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getBrand()
    print("Brand Id: %s" % brand['id'])
    childAccounts = client['SoftLayer_Brand'].getOwnedAccounts(id=brand['id'])
    pprint.pprint(childAccounts)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

### Retrieve available permissions

```
"""
Retrieve all available permissions

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission/getAllObjects

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    permissions = client['SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission'].getAllObjects()
    pprint.pprint(permissions)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

Comment: Thanks bro, the code worked and I am able to get the permissions and child accounts as well. The code for getting permissions, those permissions are portal permissions right?

Answer (score 0):

The **hasEncryptionAtRest** property will provide this information, you can try the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$storageId/getObject?objectMask=mask[hasEncryptionAtRest]

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$storageId** with your own values

**References**:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getObject)

---

> **Updated**

Here a Python script for it using **get_iscsi** method

```
"""
This script retrieves storage with hasEncryptionAtRest

Important manual pages:
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/managers/iscsi.py

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Define iscsi's identifier
volumeId = 16933699

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
iscsiManager = SoftLayer.ISCSIManager(client)

try:
    result = iscsiManager.get_iscsi(volumeId, mask='hasEncryptionAtRest')
    pprint.pprint(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

---

> **Updated 2**

---

### To get account's public ip addresses

This script will help to retrieve information from public ip address from your account
    """
    This script retrieves account's public ip addresses

```
Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getIpAddresses

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Define an objectFilter to get public ips
objectFilter = {"ipAddresses": {"subnet": {"addressSpace": {"operation": "PUBLIC"}}}}
# Define an object mask to get id and ipaddress from ips
objectMask = 'id,ipAddress'
# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getIpAddresses(mask=objectMask, filter=objectFilter)
    pprint.pprint(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

---

> **Updated 3**

---

### To get account's public ip addresses and check them into blacklist hosts

Unfortunately, there is not any SL API service that can help for it, but reviewing the following link,

- [DNS Black List / RBL Checking in
  Python](https://www.adampalmer.me/iodigitalsec/2014/11/22/dns-black-list-rbl-checking-in-python/)

You can try with that to check the ip addresses, so the script:

```
"""
This script retrieves account's public ip addresses 

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getIpAddresses

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import dns.resolver

bls = ["zen.spamhaus.org", "spam.abuse.ch", "cbl.abuseat.org", "virbl.dnsbl.bit.nl", "dnsbl.inps.de",
    "ix.dnsbl.manitu.net", "dnsbl.sorbs.net", "bl.spamcannibal.org", "bl.spamcop.net",
    "xbl.spamhaus.org", "pbl.spamhaus.org", "dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net", "dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net",
    "dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net", "db.wpbl.info", "dyn.nszones.com", "bl.nszones.com"]

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Define an objectFilter to get public ips
objectFilter = {"ipAddresses": {"subnet": {"addressSpace": {"operation": "PUBLIC"}}}}
# Define an object mask to get id and ipaddress from ips
objectMask = 'id,ipAddress'
# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    ips = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getIpAddresses(mask=objectMask, filter=objectFilter)
    for ip in ips:
        print(ip['ipAddress'])
        for bl in bls:
            try:
                my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
                query = '.'.join(reversed(ip['ipAddress'].split("."))) + "." + bl
                answers = my_resolver.query(query, "A")
                answer_txt = my_resolver.query(query, "TXT")
                print '    IP: %s IS listed in %s (%s: %s)' % (ip['ipAddress'], bl, answers[0], answer_txt[0])
            except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
                print '    IP: %s is NOT listed in %s' % (ip['ipAddress'], bl)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

As you see, the ips will be checked in the "bls" hosts, you can add more hosts to check, here a online web from you can retrieves a black list hosts to check:

- [Blacklist Check](https://www.whatismyip.com/blacklist-check/)

---

### To retrieve tags

```
"""
This script retrieves account's tags 

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getTags

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getTags()
    pprint.pprint(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

---

### Getting devices through a tag

```
"""
Search devices by tag

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# Example to search tags for a VSI
import SoftLayer
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Tag to search
tag ="singapore1" 

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY, endpoint_url='https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/')
searchService = client['SoftLayer_Search']

# Building the search string
searchString = "tagReferences.tag.name:%s _objectType:SoftLayer_Hardware,SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest,SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall,SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller _sort:[fullyQualifiedDomainName:asc]" % tag

try:
    result = searchService.advancedSearch(searchString)
    pprint.pprint(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

---

### Retrieve devices(tags) from a ip address list

```
"""
This script retrieve devices which belongs from a list ip addresses. 
Each device display information about its tags 

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/findByIpAddress

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Define ip addresses to search in devices (HW/VSI)
ips = ['159.8.30.72', '159.122.15.65', '127.0.0.1']

# Object mask to get tag information
objectMask = 'mask[tagReferences[id,tag[id,name]]]'

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    for ip in ips:
        print("Ip Address: %s" % ip)
        result = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].findByIpAddress(ip, mask=objectMask)
        if not result:
            result = client['SoftLayer_Hardware'].findByIpAddress(ip, mask=objectMask)
        if not result:
            print("      There not exists a server with this ip address")
        else:
            print("      Device Ip: %s, Hostname: %s Domain: %s" % (result['id'], result['hostname'], result['domain']))
            for tag in result['tagReferences']:
                if tag:
                    print("          TagReferencesId: %s   TagId: %s   TagName: %s" % (tag['id'], tag['tag']['id'], tag['tag']['name']))

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

---

### To retrieve account's devices (HW/VSI)

```
"""
This script retrieve devices HW and VSI

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from prettytable import PrettyTable

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

#Define an object mask to get public and private ip
mask = 'mask[primaryIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress]'

#table = BeautifulTable()
table = PrettyTable(["Id", "Hostname", "Domain", "Public IP", "Private IP", "Type"])
try:
    vsis = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getVirtualGuests(mask=mask)
    for vsi in vsis:
        if 'primaryIpAddress' not in vsi:
            vsi['primaryIpAddress'] = 'None'
        table.add_row([vsi['id'], vsi['hostname'], vsi['domain'], vsi['primaryIpAddress'] , vsi['primaryBackendIpAddress'], "Virtual Guest"])
    hws = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getHardware(mask=mask)
    for hw in hws:
        if 'primaryIpAddress' not in hw:
            hw['primaryIpAddress'] = 'None'
        table.add_row([hw['id'], hw['hostname'], hw['domain'], hw['primaryIpAddress'], hw['primaryBackendIpAddress'], "Hardware"])
    print(table)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

Comment: thankyou so much.It's working So actually my iSCSI storage device has no encrytpion, the code returned a dictionary in which one of the keypair stated :  'hasEncryptionAtRest': False
This means that there is no encryption on that particular device right?

Comment: Yes, that's the exactly meaning, **true = Encrypted, false = No encrypted**

Comment: Thanks a lot!
i have one more query can you suggest me how do we extract or pull all public ip addresses for my account in SoftLayer with the help of API's.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, please see the **Updated 2** in my answer and let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Thank you so much i was able to retrieve all public ips for my account. I have one more query, is there anyway to detect blacklisted ip addresses among the retrieved public ips, if so can you kindly assist me in retrieving the list of blacklisted ip addresses? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that you need an extra tool for this or can you do this operation in portal? or is there a way/steps that you follow to verify this for a specific ip?

Comment: Exactly that's what I wanted to know from you is there any way we can verify this specifically for each ip???
Actually I wanted to know that whether it is possible by any means to know , whether a public Ip address is blacklisted or not.
 Are there any specific API services that would help in retrieving this information?

Comment: Please, review the **Updated 3** in my answer, I hope it helps. Let me know if you need further assistance please

Comment: Hi brother, Thank you so much, Actually I did something else, I took the help of Xforce Exchange API ( https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com) i subscribed, got the API username and password passed those as headers for authentication and all the public ips which i obtained with the help of ur code, validated them against the API code of Xforce to check for blacklisted Ip addresses. Fortunately, it worked and i was able to get the information. Anyways Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Amazing, that's great!

Comment: how can we replicate any data on serverA to another server called sever B ?
And what if server A is down entirely and i would like to enable server B so that the customer doesnt face any discrepancy or disturbance?

Comment: The best way would be to use an image template or reload one, in case that you have a server already provisioned. In that case each server will not depend from the other

Comment: Hi bro...Actually I would like to know from where the virtual machine receives the traffic, i mean if it is receving the responses from a particular source how can we know those details using SoftLayer API's. Please assist me in determining the API that is required here..

Comment: My apologies for delay, there is nothing in the API to retrieve information about which traffic or the source from it, you can use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

Comment: Thanks bro and yeah, i found out that there is no such API to retrieve the traffic information, though by using loadbalancer class we can get the routing types for the account. I tried it. Anyways thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi brother. I need a help as you well know that my questions were related to Softlayer and their APIs . Do you know any AWS APIs to retrieve the public ips and get the disk encryption status details. If so i would be very thankful if u let me know the source. Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Hello :)  not sure about AWS APIs to retrieve the public ips and get the disk encryption status, are you referring to Amazon Web Services?

Comment: Ups, unfortunately I'm not sure how AWS API works, you should submit a forum with tag AWS or ticket to there, sorry but If you have any other question related to SoftLayer, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: sure. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hi Ruber. I have a query regarding the syntax which you have advised in order to fetch the encryption status of disks in softlayer. Are there any changes made to the API documentation becuase it won't like it used to before. Please acknowledge me if there are any changes that need to be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm able to retrieve the encryption information through Python and Rest, or which of the calls you have problems?

Comment: Actually I am able to get the details now bro. Thanks for responding, while saving or may be i made some syntax error. Now it is working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Hi bro, i would like to any if there any python APIs that can fetch the information about tags in Softlayer. Can you let me know what might be the typical tags that are used in Softlayer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added in my answer a script to get tags in: **To retrieve tags** section, you can set any tag like: virtual123, dal09device1, etc etc, let me know if you need assistance with it or any doubt :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am getting a response which looks like this
{'internal': 0, 'id': 1033597, 'name': 'singapore1', 'accountId': 1249861}
Can you explain me what internal  means. I assume name is the tag which I am looking for. thanks in advance

Comment: The response means that you have one tag in your account, in this case "singapore1" is the tag name, this tag can be attached to Virtual Servers or Hardware, in order that you can look them for it. If you would like to know which HW/VSI have this tag tagged, try this script: see in my answer **Getting devices through a tag**

Comment: IIf the response is empty, it means that you don't have any device tagged with the tag

Comment: Ok bro. thanks! I would like to know, if I have a list of blacklisted IP Addresses for an account say, is there any chance or possibility that I can know about the devices or Virtual machines that are being affected by these blacklisted IPs, like can i get the tags of those devices or VMs that are being affected becuase of the blacklisted IPs.

Comment: I created a script that can provide you the information that you wish, see **Retrieve devices(tags) from a ip address list** section in my answer. Let me know if you have any doubt or comment

Comment: Thanks bro. Basically i will explain you my requirement. I would like to retrieve the list of all nodes present in the SoftLayer. I guess each node might have a public ip Address and a tag. I would like to know if that Ip Address is blacklisted . if it is blacklisted, then i would want to retrieve the ip address of that node and the tag. Is that feasible . please assist me in knowing abt this. thanks in advance.

Comment: the code for Retrieve devices(tags) from a ip address list returns a response "There not exists any server with this ip Address" . can you explain me what does it mean?

Comment: That means that no devices has the ip address. In this line **ips = ['159.8.30.72', '159.122.15.65', '127.0.0.1']** you need to pass the ip addresses that you would like to check, in other words, the blacklist ip addresses

Comment: thanks a lot!. Are there any methods for listing the nodes in Softlayer, if so please help suggest me the source.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you really mean with "listing nodes in SoftLayer"?

Comment: I mean i would want to retrieve all the nodes for a particular SoftLayer account. Will that be possible?

Comment: Are you referring to account's VSI/HW devices?

Comment: ohh great, see **To retrieve account's devices (HW/VSI)** in my answer plz :)

Comment: Hi brother. Hope you are doing good. Actually i have a query. Can we retrieve all the child accounts that are present for a particular SoftLayer account. Is there any API for that? Please assist me.

Comment: I guess that you account is a Brand Master Account or Brand Account, take a look this forum, I believe that it can help you: [If I have Softlayer master brand account's api username and key, how can I get get all of its customers own api username and key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44115375/if-i-have-softlayer-master-brand-accounts-api-username-and-key-how-can-i-get-g) Let me know if it works or if you need further assistance

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for the url. I have 2 questions.
1) I see that we are passing username, apikey and brandId on the url . can i know what is a brandId exactly , how can i get it for my account?
2) Is there any API that retrieves the "portal permissions" for a SoftLayer Account?

Comment: Try the script that I attached in another answer:
**Retrieve child accounts from account**, it will provide information about Brand Id and child accounts from your account

Comment: Regarding to **Portal Permissions**, try this script: **Retrieve available permissions** (in my last answer added). It will retrieve information about permissions from users, please let me know if it was what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks bro, both the codes worked, for permission i got a huge response for my account. I assume these permissions are the portal permissions right? like permissions granted through the customer portal.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly. All portal's permissions are displayed with that method

Comment: Hi Ruber. Hope you are doing well. I had a question to ask you 

i would like to know about any offering in the ibmcloud/softlayer that has the capability to fetch the real time information about the change management that happens on any resource on the provider. Also I would like to know is there any way i can make use of IBM cloud function to integrate with the service to full the real time data. 
Thanks in advance.