# If I have Softlayer master brand account's api username and key, how can I get get all of its customers own api username and key?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

So I have master brand's API username and key, so I can user the SoftLayer_Account API to get a list of accounts it owns (i.e. the customers).  With the account ID of these customer accounts, I would think that I should be able to get its own users and get their API username and key, but I don't see a way.  How do I get my customer account's API username and key by using SoftLayer APIs?

I've tried using SoftLayer_Account::getUsers() but it always gives this master user info and not the customer account's users.  And I don't see any other APIs that I can use.  Please help.

Basically what I want to do is to get a list of all billing items that are associated with all the accounts that are under this master brand account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to retrieve the api keys through API from accounts(users) which belongs to your brand. but you can retrieve the billing items from each account using the below request:

```
https://$user:$apiKeyapi.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Brand/$brandId/getOwnedAccounts?objectMask=mask[masterUser[username,apiAuthenticationKeys],allBillingItems]

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$brandId** with your own information.

References:

- [SoftLayer_Brand::getOwnedAccounts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand/getOwnedAccounts)

Comment: Can I use the master brand's API username and key to cancel these billing items which are owned by end customer accounts? (i.e. use SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem() or cancelService()).  I try both on each billing item and it seems that virtual server fails to cancel on both APIs, but Object Storage succeeds on one of the APIs, but I don't see any changes in the customer account...  My guess is I cannot cancel without the end customer account's master user API username and key...

Comment: It's not possible to cancel from another accounts. If you would like to do that, the only way for that task would be: **1. Log in into BAP portal 2. Select "View Customers" label 3. Log in into the account that you would like to cancel its devices/services** 
Once you are in the account, you can get the username/apiKey from the master user from that account.

Comment: Right. I was trying to find do exactly that via APIs.  I figured since it's possible through UI, there would be a way to do it in APIs, but I guess not... oh well.. I hope the SoftLayer support has some automated way to cancel all the services and accounts under a particular brand...